# CSS in one line, cant compare free vs paid theme file

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, diff, indentation

This is annoying, I have a wordpress theme with a css file that is all in one long line. I wonder why anyone would do that. Now I have upgraded and I need to compare the old file with the new one so that I can take in the changes. Meld, diff and vimdiff show line difference. I wonder if there is some way to auto format/indent css files so that I can compare them line by line and make some sense to a simple task.

Comment: take an IDE of your choice and use the "format code" option.

Comment: "I wonder why anyone would do that" <- because it makes the file smaller if you remove all of the whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass it through a [prettifier](http://procssor.com/) before comparing.

Comment: Unfortunately prettifier too did not line'ify the css. But I fixed the problem by manually putting new lines. Upvote, for a good suggestion for future similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Its like this as it shouldnt need modification. you can use Styleneat to format it to multi-line. !Very hand tool
[Styleneat](http://www.styleneat.com/)